# How can we enable notification setting in android for app like "lock screen notification and badge icon" programatically

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, push

need to modify notification setting for android app from code such as enabling lock screen notifications, badge icon and enable floating notification pragmatically.

Comment: What efforts and code have you done till now. Please share with us.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check new features of [Android 5.0 APIs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html) for possible options that you can do.

As discussed in [Notifications](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Notifications), you can control the visibility level of notifications by calling `setVisibility()` and specify one of these values:

> - `VISIBILITY_PRIVATE`: Shows basic information, such as the notification’s icon, but hides the notification’s full content.
> - `VISIBILITY_PUBLIC`: Shows the notification’s full content.
> - `VISIBILITY_SECRET`: Shows nothing, excluding even the notification’s icon.

As for badge icons, you can use the new [LauncherApps](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/LauncherApps.html) class to get a list of launchable activities for the current user and any associated managed profiles. Your Launcher can make the managed apps visually prominent by appending a work badge to the icon drawable. To retrieve the badged icon, call `getUserBadgedIcon()`.

Lastly, for floating notifications, you may call `Notification.Builder` method when you construct the notification and `setPriority()`. Notifications with the priority field set to `PRIORITY_MAX` or `PRIORITY_HIGH` appear in a small floating window if the notification also has sound or vibration.

Hope that helps!